# Google Analytics: Conversion rate in time intervals

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've got Google Analytics running on a website and am now trying to determine the conversion rate in certain time intervals. I therefore have a table that contains

- `interval_id`
- `i.interval_start_time_utc`
- `i.interval_stop_time_utc`

Sadly, the following BigQuery query that would assign each order to an interval will not work:

```
SELECT
totals.transactions,
totals.visits,
i.interval_id
FROM [123456.ga_sessions_20160609]
INNER JOIN intervals i ON i.interval_start_time_utc < visitStartTime AND visitStartTime < i.interval_end_time_utc
```

This throws the error

```
ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table [...]
```

so I gather that BigQuery simply doesn't do range joins. Is there another way to do this short of doing a full join and then paring down? Are there entirely different, better approaches for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery Standard SQL doesn't have this limitation  - see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

If yo want to make with BigQuery Legacy SQL - try something like below

```
SELECT
  totals.transactions,
  totals.visits,
  i.interval_id
FROM [123456.ga_sessions_20160609]
CROSS JOIN intervals i 
WHERE i.interval_start_time_utc < visitStartTime 
AND visitStartTime < i.interval_end_time_utc
```

Comment: I've got about 5000 of these intervals so the cross join is a pretty expensive operation. Any way I could approach this differently?

Comment: if you are Ok to use BigQuery Standard SQL for this particular query - see first statement in my answer!

Comment: If yo are stuck with BigQuery Legacy SQl, options are not that many - but still there is a chance - if you have some spedicif deterministic pattern in your intervals that will allow transform your non-equijoin to equijoin. Shed a little light on logic behind your intervals so we might be able to help further

Comment: The intervals are always the x minutes to the left and right of some event. Essentially I'm interested in how conversion rate changes in response to a change and want to look at this in the temporal neighborhood of that change. Does that help?

Comment: I think this extra info/logic can help in transforming CROSS JOIN to BQ Legacy SQL's INNER JOIN. When i have time I can spend a little for this  - please confirm you are still looking  for solution in this direction, so I will not waste my time in case you are not

Comment: I am still very much looking for a solution to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of presenting idea - let’s simplify example
And let’s remember - we do want to make it with BigQuery Legacy SQL - not with Standard SqL where it is trivial!

> Challenge

Assume we have `visits` table:

```
SELECT visit_time FROM 
  (SELECT 2 AS visit_time),
  (SELECT 12 AS visit_time),
  (SELECT 22 AS visit_time),
  (SELECT 32 AS visit_time)
```

and `intervals` table:

```
SELECT before, after, event FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS before, 5 AS after, 3 AS event),
  (SELECT 6 AS before, 10 AS after, 8 AS event),
  (SELECT 21 AS before, 25 AS after, 23 AS event),
  (SELECT 33 AS before, 37 AS after, 35 AS event)
```

We want to extract all visits which are within event’s `before` and `after` values

This can be simply done with use of `CROSS JOIN` like below:

```
SELECT
  visit_time, event, before, after
FROM (
  SELECT visit_time FROM 
    (SELECT 2 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 12 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 22 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 32 AS visit_time),
) AS visits
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT before, after, event FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS before, 5 AS after, 3 AS event),
    (SELECT 6 AS before, 10 AS after, 8 AS event),
    (SELECT 21 AS before, 25 AS after, 23 AS event),
    (SELECT 33 AS before, 37 AS after, 35 AS event)
) AS intervals
WHERE visit_time BETWEEN before AND after
```

With result as:

```
visit_time  event   before  after    
2           3       1       5    
22          23      21      25
```

> Potential Issue

When both tables are big enough – this cross join becomes quite expensive!

> Hint

It happened that (from user’s comments) - The intervals are always the x units to the left and right of event.

> Solution

Below is proposed solution/option that uses hint/fact and makes use of `JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` between two big tables

The key here is to generate (on fly) new table that will hold all possible interval’s values based on event and x

```
SELECT event, event + delta AS point 
FROM (
  SELECT event FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS before, 5 AS after, 3 AS event),
    (SELECT 6 AS before, 10 AS after, 8 AS event),
    (SELECT 21 AS before, 25 AS after, 23 AS event),
    (SELECT 33 AS before, 37 AS after, 35 AS event)
) AS events
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT pos - 1 - 2 AS delta FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, * FROM (FLATTEN((
       SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + 2 * 2, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
  )))   
) AS deltas
```

In above code x = 2 – but you can change it in two places, for example if x = 5 you should have

```
SELECT pos - 1 - 5 AS delta FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, * FROM (FLATTEN((
     SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + 2 * 5, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
)))
```

CROSS JOIN in above code is inexpensive because deltas table is quite small

So, finally now, you can have your result with below:

```
SELECT
  visit_time, event 
FROM (
  SELECT visit_time FROM 
    (SELECT 2 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 12 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 22 AS visit_time),
    (SELECT 32 AS visit_time),
) AS visits
JOIN (
  SELECT event, event + delta AS point 
  FROM (
    SELECT event FROM
      (SELECT 1 AS before, 5 AS after, 3 AS event),
      (SELECT 6 AS before, 10 AS after, 8 AS event),
      (SELECT 21 AS before, 25 AS after, 23 AS event),
      (SELECT 33 AS before, 37 AS after, 35 AS event)
  ) AS events
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT pos - 1 - 2 AS delta FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, * FROM (FLATTEN((
         SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + 2 * 2, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
    )))   
  ) AS deltas
) AS points
ON points.point = visits.visit_time
```

With expected result

```
visit_time  event    
2           3    
22          23
```

I think above approach can work for you – but you sure need to adopt it to your particular case
I think this can be done relatively easy if you will round all your involved times up to respective minutes

Hope this will help
Share result with us if you will get this work :o)